# django html syntastic configuration in .vimrc

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, syntastic

I'm new in vim, and i've just installed syntastic, my question is how to activate syntastic to check htmldjango type, i have installed pylint and pylint-django, this is my SyntasticInfo

```
Syntastic version: 3.8.0-3 (Vim 800, Linux, GUI)
Info for filetype: htmldjango
Global mode: active
Filetype htmldjango is active
The current file will be checked automatically
Available checkers: -
Currently enabled checkers: -
```

Thankyou

Comment: Syntastic doesn't have any useful checkers for `htmldjango`.  You should consider reading the manual anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons this isn't working. First, to get pylint-django to "attempt" to check an htmldjango file, you'd have to insert this into your .vimrc file:

```
let g:syntastic_python_pylint_args = "--load-plugins pylint_django"
let g:syntastic_htmldjango_checkers = ['python/pylint']
```

Note that you have to specify `'python/pylint'` as the checker as this is a foreign checker to the htmldjango filetype.

That will fix your `SyntasticInfo` issue:

```
Currently enabled checker: python/pylint
```

***HOWEVER***, currently python-pylint doesn't support djangohtml templates at all so even once you've done this you'll be disappointed and get all kinds of syntax errors...because the checker only supports django model and view filetypes...(－‸ლ)